# How to collapse explorer folders before focusing a file in vcode?

Tags: configuration, visual-studio-code

I'm using visual studio code and when I have lots of documents open in different tabs, and then I go from one tab to another, I would like vcode to collapse all the folders before focusing the file that I'm editing.

This would help me to stay focused on the location of the current file that I'm working on instead of getting distracted by other expanded folders and even avoid scrolling through the tree.

For example go from this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible out of the box, though it might be possible in an extension.

You might be interested in adding a couple shortcuts, though.

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+i",
    "command": "workbench.files.action.collapseExplorerFolders",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+alt+i",
    "command": "workbench.files.action.showActiveFileInExplorer",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
}
```

I put together a quick extension that can do this, though. If you want to see the source for it, look [here](https://github.com/hoovercj/vscode-api-playground/blob/FocusActiveEditor/src/extension.ts). You can clone that branch and build it yourself. If you just want to install the .vsix manually, you can find that [here](https://github.com/hoovercj/vscode-api-playground/blob/master/vsix/vscode-api-playground-focus-active-editor-0.0.1.vsix).